# Transposição de matriz

Tags: python, numpy

quero entender o sentido da tupla que o seguinte código passou dentro do comando .transpose, fui atrás da documentação mas não me ficou claro:

arr = np.arange(16).reshape((2,2,4))

arr.transpose((1,0,2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que lembrar que o `numpy.ndarray` não é só pra matrizes bidimensionais, como estamos acostumados, mas sim, para "arrays multidimensionais" - então, se você tem uma matriz bidimensional, e não passa nenhum parâmetro, ele faz a transposição como estamos acostumados.

Se o parâmetro for passado, ele indica quais eixos serão trocados com quais - isso é, no exemplo que você passou, a posição "0" indica o eixo zero - o valor "1" passado ali indica que esse eixo da posição 0 vai ser "realocado" para o eixo "1". O valor na posição "1" recebe o valor "0", indicando que o eixo "1" vai passar a ser o eixo "0". E por fim, o "2" na posição "2" indica que esse eixo não será alterado.

Ou seja, nesse exemplo específico, se você pensar na estrutura que você criou como 4 matrizes 2 X 2 "empilhadas" -- voc}e está dizendo pra transpor os dois primeiros eixos: cada uma dessas 4 matrizes 2 x 2, e manter a mesma ordem das matrizes.

Abaixo eu faço um outro exemplo onde crio uma estrutura que pode ser visualizada mais facilmente como "3 matrizes 2x2", e peço para manter o primeiro eixo, e transponho os outros 2 - resultado, nessa visualização, cada uma das "matrizinhas 2x2" aparece transposta:

```py
In [45]: a = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 2, 2))                                                                                                                          

In [46]: a                                                                                                                                                             
Out[46]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])

In [47]: b = np.transpose(a, (0, 2, 1))                                                                                                                                

In [48]: b                                                                                                                                                             
Out[48]: 
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 1,  3]],

       [[ 4,  6],
        [ 5,  7]],

       [[ 8, 10],
        [ 9, 11]]])
```